# Make Woocommerce checkout state field required

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, state, checkout

So this problem may have a easy solution, but I'm stuck for the moment. After the last update (Woocommerce 3.3.5) I have a problem with the state field on the checkout page, because it is not mandatory and people just skip it. I really need this thing to be mandatory, because I have connected my website to the delivery company server through and API to send the order info directly to them.

I tried adding this to my functions.php and the thing is that when I go to the checkout page, the field has an asterisk, but for like one second.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'woo_filter_state_billing', 
10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 
'woo_filter_state_shipping', 10, 1 );

function woo_filter_state_billing( $address_fields ) { 
$address_fields['billing_state']['required'] = true;
return $address_fields;
}
function woo_filter_state_shipping( $address_fields ) { 
$address_fields['shipping_state']['required'] = true;
return $address_fields;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default in Last woocommerce version 3.3.5, state field is required… So in your case something is making that field "not" required.

You can try this *(work for billing and shipping fields at the same time)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'make_state_field_required', 90, 1 );
function make_state_field_required( $address_fields ) {
     $address_fields['state']['required'] = true;

     return $address_fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It could works.

Comment: Thanks! It works! And actually the code that I used before works too.... but the asterisk dissapears from the field. Very strange...

Comment: @danski. yes strange as you say. I dont have that on my different clients and test servers.

Answer (score 1):

This worked better for me as of January 2019

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'woo_filter_state_billing', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'woo_filter_state_shipping', 10, 1 );
function woo_filter_state_billing( $address_fields ) {
  $address_fields['billing_state']['required'] = true;
    return $address_fields;
}
function woo_filter_state_shipping( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['shipping_state']['required'] = true;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you mean "country"? I had that problem, being that field inexplicably optional.
In that case, the code would be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'make_country_field_required', 90, 1 );
function make_country_field_required( $address_fields ) {
     $address_fields['billing_country']['required'] = true;

     return $address_fields;
}
```