# Custom "Terms and Conditions" acceptance checkbox in Cart page Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Works on small home project, and want to add checkmark option bellow "Proceed to Checkout" button into Cart page into my Woocommerce site. I found this function, that is add that option:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'bbloomer_add_checkout_privacy_policy', 9 );

function bbloomer_add_checkout_privacy_policy() {

woocommerce_form_field( 'privacy_policy', array(
    'type'          => 'checkbox',
    'class'         => array('form-row privacy'),
    'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
    'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
    'required'      => true,
    'label'         => 'By proceeding, you are agreeing to our <a href="/termsandconditions">Terms and Conditions</a>',
)); 

}

// Show notice if customer does not tick

add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'bbloomer_not_approved_privacy' );

function bbloomer_not_approved_privacy() {
    if ( ! (int) isset( $_POST['privacy_policy'] ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please acknowledge the Terms and Conditions' ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

But seems that something is not fine with this function, because no matter if checked or not, customer can proceed to checkout page. I want to ensure that ONLY customers who will check the checkbox, can proceed to checkout. In opposite, warning message will be shown at top.

[image]

Can someone to tell me where is issue with this function or to point me to some working solution? Thanks in advance. This is image how currently looks with this function i posted before.

Comment: Just an offhand guess.... add the 'required' class. Some themes use that to make a field required.. Otherwise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485012/make-woocommerce-checkout-state-field-required should help.

Comment: Can you post complete code as asnwer pls so i can accept it if is fine?

Comment: Sorry, duty calls. If you want it done for you just go with Loic's answer. He knows his stuff, so I won't argue, as much as I'd like to.

Comment: @DorotiHenridgz Just updated the timer delay to a smaller value (3500 milli seconds instead of 10000)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will work in cart page for your privacy policy checkbox **using mandatory jQuery code** to make it work as "proceed to checkout" button is just linked to checkout page without submitting any data.

**The code will disable the button on start:**

[image]

**It use "Sweet alert 2" JS message** to display an error message on button click when the checkbox is not checked:

[image]

The complete code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'cart_privacy_policy_checkbox', 5 );
function cart_privacy_policy_checkbox() {

    woocommerce_form_field( 'privacy_policy', array(
        'type'          => 'checkbox',
        'class'         => array('form-row privacy'),
        'label_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox checkbox'),
        'input_class'   => array('woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox input-checkbox'),
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => sprintf( __( "I've read and accept the %s", "woocommerce" ),
                           '<a href="privacy-policy">'.__( "Privacy Policy", "woocommerce" ).'</a>' ),
    ));

    // jQuery code start below
    ?>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@8.8.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/promise-polyfill@8.1.0/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var a = '.checkout-button',     b = '#privacy_policy',
        c = '<?php echo wc_get_checkout_url(); ?>',     d = 'disabled';

        // Set disable button state
        $(a).addClass(d).prop('href', '#');

        // Woocommerce Ajax cart events
        $('body').on('updated_cart_totals removed_from_cart', function(){
            if( ! ( $(a).hasClass(d) && $(b).prop('checked') ) ){
                $(a).addClass(d).prop('href', '#');
            }
        })

        // On button click event
        $('body').on('click', a, function(e){
            if( ! $(b).prop('checked') ) {
                // Disable "Proceed to checkout" button
                e.preventDefault();
                // disabling button state
                if( ! $(a).hasClass(d) ){
                    $(a).addClass(d).prop('href', '#');
                }
                // Sweet alert 2
                swal({
                    title:  '<?php _e("Pricacy Policy", "woocommerce"); ?>',
                    text:   '<?php _e("Please acknowledge the privacy policy Terms and Conditions", "woocommerce"); ?>',
                    type:   'error',
                    timer:  3500,
                    showConfirmButton: false
                });
            }
        });

        // On checkbox change event
        $(b).change(function(){
            if($(this).prop('checked')){
                if( $(a).hasClass(d) ){
                    $(a).removeClass(d).prop('href', c);
                }
            } else {
                if( ! $(a).hasClass(d) ){
                    $(a).addClass(d).prop('href', '#');
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[Sweet Alert Two documentation](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for this code!

It works for me, except for when the cart is updated via ajax such as when deleting an item.

In that situation, the checkbox no longer enables the Proceed to Checkout button unless I refresh the page. I finally found a [solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-disable-ajax-cart-sub-total-update-functionality-in-cart-page/):

Add the following snippet to the header to reload the cart page after an item is deleted from the cart.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_cart_totals', function () {
    location.reload( true );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Note: The jquery snippet to reload page upon updating the cart worked only on desktop when I placed it in the page "header".
I got it to work on both mobile and desktop by adding it "after content" instead.